# hibernate not found mysql class in maven project

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I created a maven project in eclipse Helios and added "hibernate-search 4.0.0.Final" and "mysql-connector-java 5.1.18" to pom.xml dependencies. Both downloaded and exist in .m2 directory. but when I run this code:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

just to create tables in DB to import previously provided values in tables, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.leemoo.test.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:19)
    at net.leemoo.test.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
    at net.leemoo.test.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:9)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2266)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1735)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1775)
    at net.leemoo.test.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8]
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:73)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$1.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:99)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:138)
    ... 14 more
```

I don't know what to do? I googled this error but no success. plz help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like something (or someone) has put the JDBC URL in a property that is suppose to contain a class name.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    Could not load requested class : 
    jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
```

That is not a class name, and is should be.

Check your configuration properties ...

Answer (score 2):

In your Hibernate config file, you specified the URL of your database where Hibernate searches for the dialect of your database:

```
Dialect class not found: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
```

The dialect must be a class (`org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect`, for example).

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#tutorial-firstapp-configuration